# Tensorflow: docker image and -gpu suffix

Tags: docker, tensorflow, pip, dependencies, gpu

In the Docker image for Tensorflow with GPU support (for example: `tensorflow/tensorflow:2.2.0-gpu`) the installed python package is `tensorflow-gpu` (as shown in `pip freeze`).

Installing any python package that depends on `tensorflow` triggers the installation of tensorflow itself, although it's already installed under a different name (because -- correctly -- `tensorflow-gpu` != `tensorflow`).

Is there a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an instruction to install a fake `tensorflow` "package" that only writes the metadata without adding the duplicate sources:

```
$ python -c 'from setuptools import setup; setup(name="tensorflow", version="2.2.0")' install
```

In the docker image this would look like this:

```
FROM tensorflow/tensorflow:2.2.0-gpu
RUN python -c 'from setuptools import setup; setup(name="tensorflow", version="2.2.0")' install
RUN pip install my-requirements
RUN pip uninstall -y tensorflow  # cleaning up
```

Comment: i had thought of "faking" a tensorflow package, but the `-c ...` one-liner is quite a work of art :) thanks, it worked great

Comment: :-) glad I could help!