# Install Tensorflow Object Detection API without replacing existing Tensorflow package

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, amazon-sagemaker, object-detection-api

I'm trying to build a custom container image based on AWS SageMaker 763104351884.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/tensorflow-training:2.3.0-gpu-py37-cu102-ubuntu18.04 image and following the instructions in https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#tensorflow-object-detection-api-installation

However, it seems that when I run the following commands, `pip install` replaces the already existing TensorFlow package with `tensorflow-2.3.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl` which doesn't support AWS's CPU instructions and GPU devices.

```
# From within TensorFlow/models/research/
cp object_detection/packages/tf2/setup.py .
python -m pip install .
```

How can I install the Object Detection API without replacing existing TensorFlow? I tried `python -m pip install --ignore-installed .` but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

**Update 1:**

It seems that the already installed `tensorflow` for that AWS docker image isn't detected by `pip` even though it's available in `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow`. This is why `pip` still attempts to install it even with `--ignore-installed`.

As a workaround, I make a copy of the directory and then replace the newly installed one with it.

```
mv /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/ /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow.cpy/
# From within TensorFlow/models/research/
cp object_detection/packages/tf2/setup.py .
python -m pip install .
rm -r /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/
mv /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow.cpy/ /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/
```

Comment: You can install a fake `tensorflow` package containing no data; check out [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61924551/2650249) for details. Don't forget to change the version from `2.2.0` to `2.3.0` in that snippet, of course. Install the empty `tensorflow` fake to prevent installing the real `tensorflow` package, then run `python -m pip install .`